# R matrix operation

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix (15000 x 3000). The goal is to generate a new matrix according to the original matrix and initial values. For example, the criteria I would like to implement is this:

This is how my code is setup as of now.

```
DF1[1,]=1

for( i in 2:2000 ) {
    for( j in 1:15000 ) {

              if(DF[j,i] == 1 && DF1[j-1,i] == 0)
                DF1[j,i] = 1
              else if(DF[j,i] == 0 && DF1[j-1,i] == 1)
                DF1[j,i] = 0
              else DF[j,i,1] = DF1[j-1,i]

    }
}
```

DF is the original matrix.

DF1 is the new formed matrix

My question: Is there any other way to do this? A faster way?

Since nested loops do not work well, I try to use apply, but I do not know how to write the function, because it is related to two matrices.

---

An example

```
x <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
NA, 0L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), .Dim = c(4L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, NULL))
x
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1   NA    1    0    1    1
#[2,]    0    0    0   NA   NA    0
#[3,]    0   NA    1    0    1    1
#[4,]   NA    0    0   NA    0    0
```

And the loop (which doesnt work)

```
for( i in 1:4 ) { 
     for( j in 2:4 ) { 
         if(x[j,i] == 1 && y[j-1,i] == 0) { 
            y[j,i] = 1 
         }else{
            if(x[j,i] == 0 && y[j-1,i] == 1) {
               y[j,i] = 0 
         }else{ 
            y[j,i] = y[j-1,i]
         }
     }
   }
```

Comment: `DF[j,i,1]` 3-dimensional?

Comment: NO，should be DF[j,i]

Comment: winnie, it would be great if you could add a small example with the input matrix, and the expected outcome. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the example. Can you check that i have copied it to your question correctly. Note that i changed the index  `y[j,i,1]` to `y[j,i]` - is that right??

Comment: What is the error message you get? The code you showed for `x` and `y` is missing a `}` at the end. You haven't initialised `y`. Matrix `x` contains `NA`; you can't test equality with a number. What should `y` be when there is an entry `NA` in `x`? You should use the builtin `is.na`.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to begin with sample `x` and `y`, as well as matrix that you expect to obtain? Only then proceed to describe what you have tried and why you think it has failed. Right now I find your question too demanding - not because problem is difficult, but because understanding what exactly **is** a problem is difficult.

Comment: yes , it should be y[j,i] .but you have forget matrix Y.y [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [1,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 [2,] NA NA NA NA NA NA [3,] NA NA NA NA NA NA [4,] NA NA NA NA NA NA，I try to assign values to Y by the nested loops,but x,y are large matrixs in my original problem, I wonder if there exists other answers,thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `f1` uses the nested loops. (To get rid of the problem that comparison with `NA` results in the non-logical value `NA`, I replaced `NA` by `Inf`.)
Careful reading of the algorithm represented by the loops leads to the alternative `f2`:

```
f1 <- function( x, initialValues = 1 )
{
  x[which(is.na(x))] <- Inf
  y <- matrix(NA,nrow(x),ncol(x))
  y[1,] <- initialValues

  for( i in 1:ncol(x) ) { 
    for( j in 2:nrow(x) ) { 
      if(x[j,i] == 1 && y[j-1,i] == 0) { 
        y[j,i] = 1 
      }else{
        if(x[j,i] == 0 && y[j-1,i] == 1) {
          y[j,i] = 0 
        }else{ 
          y[j,i] = y[j-1,i]
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(y)
}

f2 <- function( x, initialValues = 1 )
{  
  g <- function(v)
  {
    m <- cumsum(!is.na(v))
    v[which(!is.na(v))[m]]
  }

  x[which(!(x %in% 0:1))] <- NA
  x[1,] <- initialValues
  return( apply(x,2,g) )
}
```

The function `g` fills `NA`-gaps in the vector `v`: `g(v)[i]` is equal to `v[j]` where `j` is the largest index such that `j<=i` and `v[j]!=NA`.
(Proof by induction: `v[which(!is.na(v))]` contains the non-`NA` values in `v`. If `v[i]==NA` then `m[i]==m[i-1]` and `g(v)[i]==v[which(!is.na(v))[m[i]]]==v[which(!is.na(v))[m[i-1]]==g(v)[i-1]`. Otherwise `m[i]==m[i-1]+1`, hence `g(v)[i-1]==v[which(!is.na(v))[m[i-1]]]==v[which(!is.na(v))][m[i-1]]` and `g(v)[i]==v[which(!is.na(v))[m[i]]]==v[which(!is.na(v))][m[i]]==v[which(!is.na(v))][m[i-1]+1]`, the next non-`NA` value.)

`f2` is faster than `f1`, in particular for large matrices.
Small matrix from the question:

```
> library(microbenchmark)

> x <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
+                  NA, 0L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), .Dim = c(4L, 6 .... [TRUNCATED] 

> microbenchmark( f1(x), f2(x) )
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
 f1(x) 433.864 461.2645 482.9120 471.6805 480.059 920.716   100
 f2(x) 379.518 387.6700 402.9235 391.7465 414.617 620.453   100

> all(f1(x)==f2(x))
[1] TRUE
```

Larger matrix:

```
> set.seed(1)

> n <- 200

> m <- 300

> big_x <- matrix(sample(0:10,n*m,replace=TRUE),n,m)

> big_x[sample(1:(n*m),floor((n*m)/3))] <- NA

> microbenchmark( f1(big_x), f2(big_x) )
Unit: milliseconds
      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 f1(big_x) 360.42174 495.63713 662.54576 772.42981 778.18100 890.0092   100
 f2(big_x)  33.54202  38.65849  62.25661  67.82429  72.42288 188.2729   100

> all(f1(big_x)==f2(big_x))
[1] TRUE
>
```

Even larger:

```
> set.seed(1)

> n <- 800

> m <- 1000

> huge_x <- matrix(sample(0:10,n*m,replace=TRUE),n,m)

> huge_x[sample(1:(n*m),floor((n*m)/3))] <- NA

> microbenchmark( f1(huge_x), f2(huge_x) )
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq       max neval
 f1(huge_x) 4002.4121 7759.2438 8149.821 8466.4698 8950.172 10087.251   100
 f2(huge_x)  311.4259  520.5374  751.874  774.2699 1010.188  1228.504   100

> all(f1(huge_x)==f2(huge_x))
[1] TRUE
>
```

A matrix of size 15000 times 3000, mentioned in the question:

```
> set.seed(1)

> n <- 15000

> m <- 3000

> x_15k.3k <- matrix(sample(0:1,n*m,replace=TRUE),n,m)

> x_15k.3k[sample(1:(n*m),floor((n*m)/3))] <- NA

> microbenchmark( f1(x_15k.3k), f2(x_15k.3k), times=1 )
Unit: seconds
         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max
 f1(x_15k.3k) 389.47262 389.47262 389.47262 389.47262 389.47262 389.47262
 f2(x_15k.3k)  19.97606  19.97606  19.97606  19.97606  19.97606  19.97606
 neval
     1
     1

> all(f1(x_15k.3k)==f2(x_15k.3k))
[1] TRUE
>
```

Comment: you are so smart !!! Thank you for your enthusiastic replies .but it's little difficult for me to understangding you algorithm,en,since I am new to R,could you recommend me a book  of learning  basic algorithms(Chinese better,I am not good at English)？I 'd appreciate you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know any such book. I enhanced my answer by an explanation of the function `g`. In addition, I included the possibility to choose arbitrary values for the first row. They do not have to be all 1.

Comment: yes,I also notice the result do not related to the initial value.